# pip source requirement versioning

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I'm using pip requirements files to manage a virtualenv for a project. There are some modules that are either not regularly updated on PyPi or I require a development version. In this case, pip has a great feature to pull from source. I can place this in my requirements file:

```
hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration@fad7080fe769
```

The problem with this is that it always downloads the package every time `pip -r` is run. Instead, I can specify an egg name so it will know it's already installed:

```
hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration@fad7080fe769#egg=django-registration
```

The problem I'm having now is that if I update the hash in the URL, the module is not updated unless I force updating by passing `-U` to `pip`. This takes a long time because *every* package is updated in the requirements file.

Is there some way to bump a version number when the repository hash is updated so pip will know an update is required?

Comment: The first is an open issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/166; I don't know what to do about the second.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest thing to do is to add a version string to the egg name e.g.

`hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration@fad7080fe769#egg=django-registration-1.2`

And then bump the version string whenever you change the hash

Comment: This definitely doesn't work. If the egg name is anything other than the real name, it just downloads the package again every time.